# reload particular component on event from another component in angular 6

Tags: angular

I have 2 components when i passing value from component 1  to component 2 using Router.Navigate method both component 1 and component 2 is getting reloaded instead of component 2 reload only

component 1.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getFilter();
}
submit(){
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/home', { skipLocationChange: true });
  setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate(['/category']));
} 
getFilter() {
  this.getFiltersFromLS();
  this.dataservice.getFilter().subscribe(datas => {
  this.filters  = datas;
  });
}
```

component 1.html

```
<li *ngFor="let data of label">
   <mat-checkbox   (change)="submit(data.val)"  value="{{data.val}}">
      <span class="attributes"> {{data.value}}</span>
   </mat-checkbox>
</li>
```

component 2.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getcategory();
}
getCategory() {
  this.getFiltersFromLS();
  this.dataservice.getCategory().subscribe(data => {
  this.category  = data;
  });
}
```

Comment: you have another router.navigateByUrl right before that

Comment: submit method has 2 router navigations!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in for submit function instead of two router navigations. This will load home component and share the data skipLocationChange as query string.

```
submit(){
  this.router.navigate(['/home', { skipLocationChange: true }]);
}
```